# How to deal with very long arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a `longArray` which contains other long `arrays` at the beginning of my code(think of it as a database). I'm afraid if it slows down the speed of my code.

If I still want both **execution speed** and the `longArray`, What do you recommend?

I thought if I could put my array into a function and access its data only when I need the array data it would be a solution, but it seems there is no way to do that ...

```js
function foo (){
var longArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

console.log(a)
```

Comment: I can't figure out why you have logged `a`?

Comment: Your array would have to be really quite sizeable to cause performance issues in modern browsers. Are you asking hypothetically, or are you actually running into performance issues?

Comment: There is a way to do that, but it would make it much worse. You cannot simultaneously HAVE and NOT HAVE an array present in the memory. It either is, or isn't there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to process the whole array at once, you can save it in chunks(for example in different files or variables) and then fetch and process them chunk by chunk.

If you want the whole array, you should know that the whole array must be stored in memory in runtime, so if the array is very large, it is definitely going to slow down your processing speed.